# Store dateTime with custom culture

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, datetime, cultureinfo

I have a page in asp.net MVC that gets a datetime in persian and store it in database in christmas datetime.I changed my culture to persian in order to show dates and times in persian language,everything works fine,I can store datetime with DateTime.Now in database,but when I want to get a datetime in from user in textbox(user input comes with persian datetime) and store it I get an out of range error says

> The conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value

I tried to get datetime value from FormCollection object and convert it to datetime but I got no luck,

This is my View:

```
<form action="/Accounting/TempDocument/Insert" method="post" id="insert-form">
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="row">
        <div class="form-body">
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            <div class="form-group form-md-line-input">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Description, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Description, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Description" })
                    <div class="form-control-focus"> </div>
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Description, "", new { @class = "help-block" })
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group form-md-line-input">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.DocumentDate, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })

<!-- this block is for document date-->
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DocumentDate, new { @class = "form-control date-mask", @placeholder = "Document Date" })
                    <div class="form-control-focus"> </div>
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.DocumentDate, "", new { @class = "help-block" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
<!-- my form continues -->
```

This is my action:

```
 [Route("Insert")]
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> InsertAsync(AccountingDocument model, FormCollection collection)
    {
        try
        {

          // much code here
            await _service.EntInsertAsync(model);
            if (await _service.CommitAsync())
                await SetResultMessageAsync("");
        }
        catch
        {

        }
        return RedirectToAction("RenderTop");
    }
```

My global.asax class:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest()
    {

        var persianCulture = new PersianCulture();
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = persianCulture;
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = persianCulture;

    }
```

And at last my persianCulture class:

```
 public class PersianCulture : CultureInfo
{
    private readonly Calendar cal;
    private readonly Calendar[] optionals;


    public PersianCulture()
        : this("fa-IR", true)
    {
    }

    public PersianCulture(string cultureName, bool useUserOverride)
        : base(cultureName, useUserOverride)
    {
        //Temporary Value for cal.
        cal = base.OptionalCalendars[0];

        //populating new list of optional calendars.
        var optionalCalendars = new List<Calendar>();
        optionalCalendars.AddRange(base.OptionalCalendars);
        optionalCalendars.Insert(0, new PersianCalendar());


        Type formatType = typeof(DateTimeFormatInfo);
        Type calendarType = typeof(Calendar);


        PropertyInfo idProperty = calendarType.GetProperty("ID", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        FieldInfo optionalCalendarfield = formatType.GetField("optionalCalendars",
                                                              BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

        //populating new list of optional calendar ids
        var newOptionalCalendarIDs = new Int32[optionalCalendars.Count];
        for (int i = 0; i < newOptionalCalendarIDs.Length; i++)
            newOptionalCalendarIDs[i] = (Int32)idProperty.GetValue(optionalCalendars[i], null);

        optionalCalendarfield.SetValue(DateTimeFormat, newOptionalCalendarIDs);

        optionals = optionalCalendars.ToArray();
        cal = optionals[0];
        DateTimeFormat.Calendar = optionals[0];

        DateTimeFormat.MonthNames = new[] { "فروردین", "اردیبهشت", "خرداد", "تیر", "مرداد", "شهریور", "مهر", "آبان", "آذر", "دی", "بهمن", "اسفند", "" };
        DateTimeFormat.MonthGenitiveNames = new[] { "فروردین", "اردیبهشت", "خرداد", "تیر", "مرداد", "شهریور", "مهر", "آبان", "آذر", "دی", "بهمن", "اسفند", "" };
        DateTimeFormat.AbbreviatedMonthNames = new[] { "فروردین", "اردیبهشت", "خرداد", "تیر", "مرداد", "شهریور", "مهر", "آبان", "آذر", "دی", "بهمن", "اسفند", "" };
        DateTimeFormat.AbbreviatedMonthGenitiveNames = new[] { "فروردین", "اردیبهشت", "خرداد", "تیر", "مرداد", "شهریور", "مهر", "آبان", "آذر", "دی", "بهمن", "اسفند", "" };


        DateTimeFormat.AbbreviatedDayNames = new string[] { "ی", "د", "س", "چ", "پ", "ج", "ش" };
        DateTimeFormat.ShortestDayNames = new string[] { "ی", "د", "س", "چ", "پ", "ج", "ش" };
        DateTimeFormat.DayNames = new string[] { "یکشنبه", "دوشنبه", "ﺳﻪشنبه", "چهارشنبه", "پنجشنبه", "جمعه", "شنبه" };

        DateTimeFormat.AMDesignator = "ق.ظ";
        DateTimeFormat.PMDesignator = "ب.ظ";
    }

    public override Calendar Calendar
    {
        get { return cal; }
    }

    public override Calendar[] OptionalCalendars
    {
        get { return optionals; }
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess the "correct" way would be to translate your persian date to gregorian (maybe using NodaTime) and store that. Before displaying, translate back.

Comment: I was doing this like translating datetime when I want to show it to user,but when I began to Use Devexpress Component I had to change culture in order to change devexpress language.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the user enters the year for the Islamic era (current year is 1438 AH).

Then the error `The conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value` occurs on the database because your datetime column uses the `datetime` type instead of `datetime2`.

The `datetime` T-SQL datatype only supports dates in the range 1753-01-01 through 9999-12-31.

Change the datatype on the DB to `datetime2` which supports dates 0001-01-01 00:00:00.0000000 through 9999-12-31 23:59:59.9999999.

Comment: Does that islamic calendar have 12 months with the same number of days as the gregorian calendar? In other words: would it be possible to get a month-number or day-number that is "illegal" according to sql server?

Comment: hi,no user enters year of shamsi dateTime , now it's 1396
and unfortunately it does not have same number of days as datetime2 so I have to convert it,My program automatically converts values from DateTime.now which appears as 1396/01/01 format when I'm debugging but for user inputs I get this error

Comment: The C# `DateTime` supports dates from 01-01-0001 to 31-12-9999, so maybe it works on the C# side (in the debugger), but not on the DB?

Answer (score 0):

Since user possibly enter dates in Hijri calendar, probably it has year value less than SQL `datetime` supports (1753-01-01). Note that by default Gregorian system is used in both `datetime` & `datetime2` data type, regardless of culture being set.

There are some possible solutions:

1. Change data type of mapped column `DocumentDate` to datetime2 in database, which supports minimum value of `DateTime.MinValue`.
2. If you're using `SqlCommand` with parameterized query, you can define `SqlDbType.DateTime2` as DB data type in either `Parameters.Add` or `Parameters.AddWithValue`.
3. If you're using EF with EDMX, you can define property `DocumentDate` by updating corresponding column mapping to `DateTime2`.

Comment: shamsi date has 31 days for it's second month,so I cant save that date time directly.

Comment: Personally I prefer to store the date in DB as `datetime2` (Gregorian date), where conversion to Persian occurs in presentation layer (both when storing and retrieving the value). Alternatively you can utilize UDT (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-type-transact-sql), but I still couldn't find UDT usage example for Persian calendar format.